# JBoss service failure

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I get the following exception when I run JBoss:

```
Failed to start service org.wildfly.network.interface.cluster: 
    org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.network.interface.cluster:
    WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface cluster at 
org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService.start(NetworkInterfaceService.java:96)
```

This is rather generic. Does anyone know how to get more details about the root cause?
Any idea which jar file contains org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService class?

Comment: What is the full stack trace?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins: I can't post the full stack  trace. Stackoverflow complains it's too long.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins: But here is the relevant part::

`at org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService.start(NetworkInterfaceService.java:96)
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)`

There are three more lines with JDK classes.